# why javascript link not work in local host?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

PLEASE help js file does not work in localhost, when script tag in head.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    typeof "john" + "<br>" +
    typeof 3.14 + "<br>" +
    typeof false + "<br>" +
    typeof [1,2,3,4] + "<br>" +
    typeof {name:'john', age:34};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

but when it in body it works.My question .why?

Comment: use your code in onload....

Comment: do you mean F12 in mozilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your code is executed in head before the body loaded. `document.getElementById("demo")` won't find the element "demo" because it does not exist yet.

Use it on onload:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    typeof "john" + "<br>" +
    typeof 3.14 + "<br>" +
    typeof false + "<br>" +
    typeof [1,2,3,4] + "<br>" +
    typeof {name:'john', age:34};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when your are putting this js snippet inside head tag it does not know what is `<p id="demo"></p>`

But when you put it inside body tag, first DOM get parsed then js is executed. You can still put it inside head tag by using `window.load`.Here is snippet

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    typeof "john" + "<br>" +
    typeof 3.14 + "<br>" +
    typeof false + "<br>" +
    typeof [1,2,3,4] + "<br>" +
    typeof {name:'john', age:34};
}
```

[WORKING COPY](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/edpnxx7s/)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("demo")` will try to find an element with id `demo` but since the page hasn't been rendered completely yet , it won't find anything and return `null`.

use `window.onload`.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    typeof "john" + "<br>" +
    typeof 3.14 + "<br>" +
    typeof false + "<br>" +
    typeof [1,2,3,4] + "<br>" +
    typeof {name:'john', age:34};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The scripts should always be loaded at the bottom of your body, to be sure that DOM is loaded before execution. Alternatively you can use JQuery `$(document).ready(function(){ //put your code in here });`